# Fetching all channels using Getstream

Tags: node.js, chat, messaging, channel, getstream-io

I am trying to fetch all channels of a user(channel of which that user is a member). So, I got to know about this :

```
        const filter = {
            type: 'messaging',
            members: { $in: [`${req.body.id}`] },
        };
        const sort = { last_message_at: -1 };
        const channelList = await client.queryChannels(filter, sort, {
            watch: true,
            state: true,
        });
```

, by sending current user id as req.body.id.I have made a separate function for it. And when the user enters that page, I need to call that function. But when I am doing this, I am getting this error as a response :

> "StreamChat error code 4: QueryChannels failed with error: "Watch or Presence requires an active websocket connection, please make sure to include your websocket connection_id"

Please suggest whether I am doing anything wrong to fulfill this task or what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You need to call `connect` on `client` which will take you to a setting user via `setUser` because you want channel events with `watch: true`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are sending `watch: true` to `queryChannels` but `setUser` was not called or did not complete yet.

To fix this: call `await client.setUser({id})` and wait for its completion (hence the await) before `queryChannels`.